# MSI how to detect is Excel running

Tags: excel, wix, windows-installer, excel-addins

Our application is Excel add-in. We use Wix 3.10 to build MSI. Currently we can perform uninstall of the app even if Excel running with connected add-in. **I need to interrupt uninstall process if Excel is running.** We don't need to close Excel, I just need to detect is it running. If so, I need to show appropriate message to user and stop uninstall process. How to detect is Excel (any app) running during uninstall process ? 
Can I achieve desired behavior using "standard" MSI/Wix capabilities or should I write some custom action ?

Comment: CloseApplication? http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/closeapplication.html

Comment: In other words you are detouring the fact that Windows Installer lets you uninstall and keep Excel running?  Windows jumps through hoops to let this happen without a reboot, and will clear things up later when Excel finishes. There is no value in preventing the uninstall if the users and Excel are happy to keep running with no issues.

Comment: It could be case if no issues, however we are experiencing some troubles: uninstall can't remove some files and remains some folders, because excel keep those files in use while running. Obviously this is not desired behaviour. I should fix this.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need a custom action to query Windows if the excel process is running and set a property with the result.  Then you can use that in a Launch Condition (Condition element)  to notify the user and block installation.

Comment: I tried this approach and it works. However I don't quite understand how to run this check with uninstallation only. I added condition REMOVE="ALL", but without any positive result, it looks like this property set up after InstallValidate, that is after LaunchCondition, thus Repair also fires this excel check. Still working on this anyway.

Comment: Schedule the custom action to run before AppSearch and use  "or Installed"  in your launch condition so it's not relevant during the uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I implemented my own custom action. This action fires on any installation mode: install/uninstall/repair etc. The action show message box that asks user to close Excel and has two buttons 'Retry' and 'Cancel'. If user press 'Retry' code repeat checking is Excel running, 'Cancel' leads to another dialog when user is asked to Proceed or really cancel.
There is action in C# (Please note that this code is used Wix SDK: `Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll`):

```
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult IsExcelRunning(Session session)
{
    session.Log("Begin IsExcelRunning.");

    MessageResult msgBoxResult = MessageResult.Cancel;
    do
    {
        session.Log("Try to find running Excel.");

        bool isExcelRunning = false;
        try
        {
            var obj = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
            isExcelRunning = null != obj;
            session.Log("IsExcelRunning = " + isExcelRunning);

            if (null != obj)
            {
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(obj);
                obj = null;
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            session.Log("Exception:" + ex);
        }

        if (!isExcelRunning)
        {
            session.Log("End IsExcelRunning.");
            return ActionResult.Success;
        }
        else
        {
            var errorRecord = new Record(1);
            errorRecord.SetInteger(1, 30000);
            try
            {
                msgBoxResult =
                    session.Message(InstallMessage.Error | (InstallMessage) MessageButtons.RetryCancel,
                        errorRecord);

            }
            catch (InstallCanceledException)
            {
                var questionRecord = new Record(1);
                questionRecord.SetInteger(1, 1602);

                if (MessageResult.Yes ==
                    session.Message(
                        InstallMessage.Error | (InstallMessage)MessageButtons.YesNo |
                        (InstallMessage)MessageBoxIcon.Question, questionRecord))
                {
                    session.Log("End SetIsExcelRunning.");
                    return ActionResult.UserExit;
                }
                else
                {
                    msgBoxResult = MessageResult.Retry;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                session.Log("Unexpected exception:" + ex);
                throw;
            }
        }
    } while (MessageResult.Retry == msgBoxResult);

    session.Log("End IsExcelRunning.");
    return ActionResult.UserExit;
}
```